# Exibir na tela os valores do vetor em c++

Tags: c++, array

Não consigo listar(exibir) os produtos cadastrado no meu Vetor.
Alguém sabe me orientar, estou aprendendo c++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int op, i=0;
    string produto[10];
    double venda[10], custo[10];
    do {

        cout << "\n\tCadastro de Produto\n";
        cout << "\n<1> Novo Produto";
        cout << "\n<2> Listar Produtos";
        cout << "\n\tOpcao: ";
        cin >> op;
        system("cls");


        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                i++;
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Produto: ";
                cin>>produto[i];
                cout<<"\nCusto: ";
                cin>>custo[i];
                cout<<"\nVenda: ";
                cin>>venda[i];

                break;

           case 2:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Os produtos Cadastrados sao:\n"<<produto;
                cout<<"\n\n\n\n";
                system ("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;

        }
    } while (op != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vanusa, você precisa ter em mente primeiramente que você está utilizando três arrays para armazenar as informações dos produtos e isto impoe um limite para o cadastro de 10 produtos em seu caso.

Para armazenar uma quantidade indefinida de elementos seria necessária a utilização de vetores propriamente ditos (definidos no include  da biblioteca padrão do c++).

Considerando este fato é necessário limitar a entrada de dados no seu programa para que um erro não seja causado ao adicionar um 11º produto.

Agora para responder especificamente sua dúvida:

É necessário efetuar um loop, acessando cada elemento do seu array, conforme demonstra o código abaixo:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    const int quantidade_de_produtos = 10;
    string produtos[quantidade_de_produtos];

    void listar_produtos()
    {
        //Percorre a lista de produtos, inclusive os que não foram preenchidos...
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidade_de_produtos; ++i)
        {
            //Verifica se há um produto no índice atual...
            if (!produtos[i].empty())
            {
                //Imprime a descrição do produto.
                cout << "Produto: " << produtos[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        produtos[0] = "Carteira";
        produtos[1] = "Sapato";
        produtos[2] = "Casaco";

        listar_produtos();

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro esta inicialmente no incremento de `i`. O `i++` deve ficar no final da estrutura.

```
case 1:
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Produto: ";
    cin>>produto[i];
    cout<<"\nCusto: ";
    cin>>custo[i];
    cout<<"\nVenda: ";
    cin>>venda[i];
    i++;

    break;
```

A primeira posição a ser inseria é **0**, então o valor de `i` só deve ser incrementado após a inserção dos dados.

Para imprimir os dados de um vetor na tela, é necessário uma estrutura `for` ou `while`

```
case 2:
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Os produtos Cadastrados sao:" << endl; # endl quebra a linha em c++
    for(int x=0; x<i; x++){
        cout << produto[x] << endl;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\n\n";
    system ("pause");
    system("cls");
    break;
```

Assim como foi inserido na posição **n** de produto, deve imprimir a posição **n**.

Answer (score 0):

```
            case 1:

            system("cls");
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            cout<<"Produto: ";
            cin>>produto[i];
            cout<<"\nCusto: ";
            cin>>custo[i];
            cout<<"\nVenda: ";
            cin>>venda[i];
            }

            break;

       case 2:
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Os produtos Cadastrados sao:\n";
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            cout<<produto[i];
            cout<<"\n\n";
            }
            cout<<"\n\n";
            system ("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;

    }
```

tenta colocar um for dentro dos case e inserir em cada ponto do vetor
mesma coisa para ler, uma outra alternativa é usar um while no lugar do for como laço indeterminado.É minha primeira vez ajudando então desculpa se tiver  algo errado.